# SQL check if column value is true

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have four columns `A,B,C,D` and are all of type `bit`.

Is there a way in SQL to check if all four column values are 1
and not 0 for a single record?

Comment: Yes, but the syntax depends on the DBMS you are using. You have tagged 2 here, SQL Server and MySQL. Tag the correct DBMS and only the correct DBMS please. When you do update your question, don't forget to post what you have tried as well.

Comment: Tag the only DBMS which you are really using.

Comment: You just need a condition in your `WHERE` clause for each column: `WHERE A=1 AND B=1 AND C=1 AND D=1`.

Comment: Does MySQL have a `BIT` data type? Didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bit-wise operators e.g.:

```
select 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
```

yields 0, which you can easily test

Comment: what i have is a table for approval check  all column must have a value 1 if even one is 0 the data will not be shown to cutomer instead using where clause is there a more efficent way of doing this

Comment: Put it in the `WHERE` @user3011926

Comment: `WHERE A & B & C & D = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to treat the Null values as 0(false). Use following query

```
Select A,B,C,D 
    from #mytable t
    where t.A = 1 
       and t.B = 1
       and t.C = 1
       and t.D = 1
```